# Why can't I call these calculations into my build, when I'm already doing it for another function

Tags: flutter, dart

The var _distancebetween is causing issues here. I don't know how to call it in my widget Build:

```
 void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition cameraPosition) async {
    
    var _distancebetween = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        lat, lng, _lastMapPosition.latitude, _lastMapPosition.longitude);
    
    _lastMapPosition = cameraPosition.target;
    var latlnglastPosition = _lastMapPosition.toString;

    setState(() {
      latlnglastPosition;
      _distancebetween;
      _lastMapPosition;
    });
  }
```

when I setState for _latlnglastPosition, and _lastMapPosition, I call them in my build like so:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var latlnglastPosition = _lastMapPosition.toString();
```

and I can easily display the text in an Ink Response field.

Why won't this work for _distancebetweenFinal?

In my build:

```
var _distancebetweenFinal = _distancebetween.toString();

print(_distancebetweenFinal);
print(_distancebetween);
```

This prints zeros... But if printed from my void _onCameraMove, it's printing the correct value. How can I pass the value from _onCameraMove into my widget build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `_onCameraMove()` in initState could work, like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    _onCameraMove();
  }
```

And make sure you make your class `Statefull` and call `initState` before `build method`

Comment: super.initState();
    _onCameraMove();

expects a positional argument. CameraPosition cameraPosition won't work. any ideas? printing zeros still with no positional argument

Comment: your cameraPosition is null